# Position of a variable within a vector

Tags: r

Does anyone know of a simple and efficient way to figure out how many values, in an unsorted vector, are greater than a variable?

My vector is 1,000,000 values long, and I have about 400 of these comparisons to make, with different vectors and variables. Any time-saving function would be appreciated...

Comment: If you have to do all 400 comparisons at once, maybe generate a histogram instead.  Otherwise, seancarmody's answer is good for returning just the values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you just want to know how many meet the condition rather than which ones meet the condition, try this:

```
vector<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
sum(vector>1)
```

Comment: @Florent, if this is "exactly what you need", then you must accept it as the correct answer by cliking in the green tickmark :D

Answer (score 2):

Just use the which function. So if I have vector,

```
vector<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
which(vector>1)
```

Outputs 2,3,4,5

Comment: Stray ) at the end of the second line.

Comment: This does not answer the question "how many". You could pass the output to `length` but the whole thing is slower and less elegant than using `sum` directly.

Answer (score -4):

if I understand what you want.
you may reorder your vector (quick sort), and after you may a search(binary search). all elements, after the first element that is > then you variable, will be >. is the opposite for <.

Comment: sorting is a bit expensive for this task, no?

Comment: especially when the data set in question is very large!

Comment: if the Vector was very large should first and then try to reorder.
average-case quick sort sorts in O (n log n) and binary search to find what we look for in o(n/2)

Comment: Note that the other solutions are O(n)